# how to fix in call Volume control

Tags: android, audio, sony, cyanogenmod, sony-xperia

Hey i have been porting AOSP to Xperi L and i have observed that the incall Volume control doesn't work. There may be some issue in HAL.I am not sure as to how to approach the issue while the issue still persists in Kitkat too. 
Would anyone be able to guide or just give a direction as to how to approach this issue...

The qcom audio that i am using is 
https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_audio

and kernel code is 
https://github.com/varunchitre15/android_kernel_sony_msm8930

Following is logcat for volume control change

```
01-13 15:50:57.068: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoipVolume: volume 80
01-13 15:50:57.068: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voip Rx Volume value 80 index 0
01-13 15:50:57.068: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoiceVolume: volume 80
01-13 15:50:57.068: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voice Rx Volume value 80 index 0
01-13 15:50:57.579: D/SettingsProvider(782): User 0 external modification to /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db; event=2
01-13 15:50:57.579: D/SettingsProvider(782): User 0 updating our caches for /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
01-13 15:50:58.449: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoipVolume: volume 100
01-13 15:50:58.449: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voip Rx Volume value 100 index 0
01-13 15:50:58.449: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoiceVolume: volume 100
01-13 15:50:58.449: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voice Rx Volume value 100 index 0
01-13 15:51:00.492: I/ActivityManager(782): Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{2677dd25 u0 com.google.android.talk/com.google.android.apps.hangouts.realtimechat.RequestWriter}
01-13 15:51:01.443: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoipVolume: volume 80
01-13 15:51:01.443: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voip Rx Volume value 80 index 0
01-13 15:51:01.443: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoiceVolume: volume 80
01-13 15:51:01.443: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voice Rx Volume value 80 index 0
01-13 15:51:02.294: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoipVolume: volume 60
01-13 15:51:02.294: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voip Rx Volume value 60 index 0
01-13 15:51:02.294: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoiceVolume: volume 60
01-13 15:51:02.294: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voice Rx Volume value 60 index 0
01-13 15:51:02.914: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoipVolume: volume 40
01-13 15:51:02.914: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voip Rx Volume value 40 index 0
01-13 15:51:02.914: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoiceVolume: volume 40
01-13 15:51:02.914: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voice Rx Volume value 40 index 0
01-13 15:51:03.885: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoipVolume: volume 20
01-13 15:51:03.885: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voip Rx Volume value 20 index 0
01-13 15:51:03.885: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoiceVolume: volume 20
01-13 15:51:03.885: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voice Rx Volume value 20 index 0
01-13 15:51:04.526: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoipVolume: volume 0
01-13 15:51:04.526: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voip Rx Volume value 0 index 0
01-13 15:51:04.526: D/ALSADevice(4506): setVoiceVolume: volume 0
01-13 15:51:04.526: D/ALSADevice(4506): setMixerControl:: name Voice Rx Volume value 0 index 0
01-13 15:51:05.837: D/AccelerometerListener(1143): orientation: vertical
```

Comment: i love your tag: *sony*

Comment: Its official sony developer tag to get sony developer support

Comment: Notice that the [CyanogenMod qcom audio repo](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_hardware_qcom_audio) has CAF (code aurora forum) branches specifically for different msm versions.  You may want to choose one that's similar to your device.  I would take a look at similar devices such as the [Samsung Express](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_samsung_expressatt/tree/cm-12.0) (msm8960) to see how they are handling sound.  Note they pull in a [common device tree](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_samsung_msm8960-common) which pulls in device/samsung/qcom-common too.

Comment: @fattire off topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259606/kernel-panic-bluetooth-connectivity-issues